# Trying to connect to server via SSH with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, web-hosting

I've got my SSH keys in place, and can log into the server just fine from my terminal, but when trying to SSH via VSCode... I get the following errors over and over again:

```
ssh fork: retry: No child processes
```

I also noticed that when VSCode is connecting to my server... I can't connect via SSH in Terminal, and I have to manually halt the processes for VSCode on the server to be able to connect again.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The error is the result of the parent process waiting the child after a fork().

The error means that your running low on resources or you have created to many processes and the bash can no longer create any process.

Can you avoid automatically connection retries?

Comment: That's really odd. I have no other processes running in CPanel. I'm not sure how VSCode is implementing its SSH policies and if I can change them, but I'll research that further.

Comment: As it turns out, it's not working because I'm using Shared Hosting and HostGator doesn't allow TCP Forwarding there (which is necessary for SSH in VSCode to function). They require a VPS or Dedicated subscription to be able to enable it... \*eyeroll\*